# kerberos authentication in sybase

Tags: sybase

we are setting up Kerberos authentication in Sybase (linux). DB version is 15.7. We are using Active directory for kerberos. We have done the configuration settings on the DB side and kerberos is successfully initialized on the DB server, we can see it from the log "00:0000:00000:00000:2013/09/19 15:47:30.96 server  Successfully initialized the security mechanism 'csfkrb5'. ASE will support use of this security mechanism."
We have generated the keytab and placed it in \etc\krb5.keytab and successfully generated the ticket as well.

But when we try to connect using isql -Sservername -V we are getting the below error.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_con_props(SET): security service layer: internal security control layer error: Unable to open security driver.
Msg 4002, Level 14, State 1:
Server 'Servername':
Login failed.
CT-LIBRARY error:
        ct_connect(): protocol specific layer: external error: The attempt to connect to the server failed.

Please someone help us on this to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Sybase DBA

Comment: Are you using MIT Kerberos ?

Comment: Yes we are using MIT kerberos.

Comment: have you also migrated the users to use ldap auth? i.e with the following cmd: `sp_modifylogin "test123", "authenticate with", "LDAP"`